# Child theme grabbing wrong location fo parent theme files

Tags: child-theme

I purchased a Wordpress theme this week, and to keep my changes separate from the original theme, I created a child theme for it. Right now it's just a barebones child theme, the style.css file and screenshot. The parent theme has several CSS and jQuery scripts that it includes. The problem however is that the child theme looks for these files in the child theme directory, rather than the parent.

For example if I am using the parent theme the location would be:

ParentTheme/js/jquery.easing.js

However in the child theme, it looks for the files here:

ChildTheme/js/jquery.easing.js

Rather than the parent theme like I would assume.

I tried copying the CSS and JS folders, but that didn't work either.

Am I doing something wrong? How would I use a child theme for a parent theme that has several CSS and JS files that are needed?

You can take a look for yourself here if you would like: http://panther.c1.vadc1.cloudweb.com/~jsfashio/

Comment: Close vote denied - this is a usual mistake theme developers make. Keep it as example on what happens if you develop crappy themes/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a commercial Theme, you really need to contact the developer for support.

That said: the Theme appears to be mis-using [**`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), when it *should* be using [**`get_template_directory_uri()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri).

Comment: Hey Chip, thank you very much for your response. The theme developer doesn't seem to want to help. But thanks to your tip about the template/stylesheet directories, I think I can get around this on my own.